# How do I recursively perform a cat with multiple pipes

Tags: awk, find, cat

I have some directories and files that looks like this:

`/my/directories/directory0/
                          |
                           -->File1.txt
                          |
                           -->File2.txt
/my/directories/directory1/
                          |
                           -->File1.txt
                          |
                           -->File2.txt
/my/directories/directory2/
                          |
                           -->File1.txt
                          |
                           -->File2.txt
/my/directories/directory3/
                          |
                           -->File1.txt
                          |
                           -->File2.txt`

These are CSV files, and I'm trying to get the 3rd column counted, and sorted from highest to lowest.

Right now I'm able to accomplish this, but only within each directoryx specifically.  For example, if I run this:

`cd /my/directories/directory0/
cat *.txt | awk -F "," '{print $3}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr > finalOutput.txt`

Then I get exactly what I want, but only with the data in that directory.  I want to cat everything from all of the /my/directories/ sub directories into a single file.

I've tried to use `ls` or `find` to accomplish this, but I can't get it working.  I know you can recursively cat this way, similar to this:

`find /my/directories/ -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} \; > finalOutput.txt`

But, I haven't been able to get this to work with a multi piped command.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with `find /my/directories/ -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} \; | awk ...`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that. I just didn't know the correct syntax after the -exec flag.  This is a valid answer because it shows the mistake in my syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with xargs:

```
$ find . -name "f?" | xargs awk -F, '{ print $3 }' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
4 3
1 z
1 three
1 c
1 5

$ find . -name "f?" -exec echo "File: " {} \; -exec cat {} \; -exec echo "----" \;
File:  ./d0/f1
1,2,3
----
File:  ./d0/f2
3,4,5
----
File:  ./d1/f1
8,9,3
----
File:  ./d1/f2
a,b,c
----
File:  ./d2/f1
x,y,z
----
File:  ./d2/f2
one,two,three
----
File:  ./d3/f1
red,yellow,3
----
File:  ./d3/f2
1,2,3
----
```

Comment: This works.  I would also like to point out to anyone that finds this answer, that William Pursell's comment on my original question also solves the problem, but by fixing my original attempt.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "File*" | xargs cut -d, -f3 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Comment: This only returns one column, and doesn't do the count.

Comment: @trueCamelType Well, neither does your example, about which you say "Then I get exactly what I want". So, basically, I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Because of the uniq command inside of my example, it does return more than one column.  It also counts the number of occurrences.

Comment: @trueCamelType I think I understand now. Use `find` to find all relevant files, regardless of directory depth, and use `cut` instead of `awk` to select a single column. Then, proceed as you originally did.